# How to restrict my custom outliner context menu to materials

Tags: python, add-on

I added a custom operator to the outliner context menu by adding the following line in my addon register function

```
bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_context_menu.append(draw)
```

draw function

```
draw(self,context):
   layout = self.layout
   layout.operator(OUTLINER_OT_myoperator.bl_idname)
```

In the outliner's Blender File panel, when I RMB-click any item, the menu shows up as expected. I only want the menu to show up if I RMB-click on a material.

In myoperator class, I'd like to use the poll function to do so. I can't use context.object as this points to an object. I tried to find different alternatives, but got nowhere

class OUTLINER_OT_myoperator(bpy.types.Operator):

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls,context):
   return context_area.type == "OUTLINER" # and context.object.type == 'MATERIAL'
```

How can restrict the poll function to materials items?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Hope to be mistaken, but not sure it is possible ATM. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206673/get-operator-command-from-context-menu  can add the dump method from the docs to outliner context menu, but only get buttons context over property fields, not outliner items. Concur that couldn't find any other context members to latch onto.